# Access one Usercontrol in different Views

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, wpf-controls, prism

Access one Usercontrol in different Views
 [image]

Here The 1st rectangle with radiobuttons and other elements is supposed to be generic user control.

The below boxes with greyed area are other views.The greyed area has to display the UserControl.As indicated with arrow only those fields are to be displayed.The greyed area will vary depending on view.Basically developer requires these generic control instead of repeating this at all places.Can someone suggest which way to go about.

Here greyed boxes views have its own viewmodel...and the usercontrol alone as its viewmodel

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm having a really hard time understand what you are trying to do ... try to simplify your question

Comment: Does each view have a diferent instance of the generic user control?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain how the generic User Control behaves on each View and why the greyed area varies its size. Does the generic **View** change its style on each one of the navigated views? Have you considered defining a Nested **Region** on each view for the generic UserControl's **View**?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to show different elements of the same `UserControl` in different places in the UI, then you could define some `bool` properties on the `UserControl` and `Bind` the `Visibility` property of the elements to them and then set them externally:

In the code behind of your `UserControl`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AreButtonsVisibleProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("AreButtonsVisible", typeof(bool), 
    typeof(YourUserControlName), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

public bool AreButtonsVisible 
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(AreButtonsVisibleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AreButtonsVisibleProperty, value); }
}
```

Then in the XAML:

```
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:ApplictaionName.Converters"
xmlns:YourControlNamespace="clr-namespace:ApplictaionName.YourControlNamespace"
...
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<Button Content="->" Visibility="{Binding AreButtonsVisible, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourControlNamespace:YourUserControl}}, 
    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
<Button Content="X" Visibility="{Binding AreButtonsVisible, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourControlNamespace:YourUserControl}}, 
    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Then where you use the `UserControl`, you can hide the `Button`s:

```
<YourControlNamespace:YourUserControl AreButtonsVisible="False" ... />
```